# Jumping to unpaired parenthesis in Vim?

Tags: vim

As Vim highlighted unpaired parenthesis (in red background in my windows which is considered as syntax error), is there a way to jump to next/previous unpaired parenthesis directly? This would include characters like `{}[]()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[(
```

to go to the previous `(`

You can use

```
])
```

to go to the next `)`

You can use

```
[{
```

to go to the previous `{`

You can use

```
]}
```

to go to the next `}`

Don't know how to go the previous `[` or the next `]`

Use `:help [(` to get online help on these commands.